# How can I find files with permissions greater than xxx but ignore files with SUID and SGID

Tags: find

I'm trying to find files with permissions that exceed 755. Using the solution from [another post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31770/find-files-which-have-a-higher-permission-than-xxx) here I have been able to get mostly what I want:

```
find /bin -type f -perm -755 ! -perm 755
```

This does ignore anything at 755 or below, but it returns files with the SUID and SGID bits set. I would like to ignore these. Is it possible to do this in one command? I've tried multiple `! -perm` arguments with both `2000` and `4000` but that didn't do anything.

I have also used `2755` and `4755` in sequential commands, but again, I would prefer covering both in one command.

I was thinking the `-o` operator would help, but I'm not sure how to do that with an argument that contains a negated pattern like I'm using. I tried it as

```
find . -type f \(-perm -2755 ! -perm 2755 -o -perm -4755 ! -perm 4755\)
```

but that just threw the `paths must precede expression` error.

Comment: Note that 760 is greater than 755 but has narrower permissions, while 77 is smaller but has wider permissions. ITYM you want to find files that have some bits among 0777 (the lowest 9 bits) set in addition to the 0755 ones (which the accepted answer covers).

Answer (score 5):

The solution that works with any [POSIX compatible find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/find.html) is the following:

```
find DIR -type f -perm -0755 ! -perm 0755 ! -perm -04000 ! -perm -02000 -print
```

As previously noted, with GNU find you can collapse the setuid and setgid tests into `! -perm /06000`.

Comment: Thanks for providing that.  BTW, there's a newer edition (Issue 7) of the POSIX standard; the new `find` specification is [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).  The wording for `-perm` is changed there, but it's just clarification, with no difference in the meaning (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand what you want, but, based on my best guess,

```
find  (starting_directory)  -type f  -perm -755  ! -perm 755  ! -perm /6000
```

would seem to do it.  `-perm /mode` means
"Any of the permission bits *mode* are set for the file." 
So `-perm /6000` should match only files that are SUID or SGID (or both),
and `! -perm /6000` should exclude those files.

BTW, I assume that the `-type -f` in your question is a typo,
since you got it right (`-type f`, without the second **`-`**)
in your second example.

---

P.S. It still doesn't do what you want,
but you can get your second example to do *something*
(i.e., list some files, and not say `paths must precede expression`)
simply by changing it to

```
find . -type f \( -perm -2755 ! -perm 2755 -o -perm -4755 ! -perm 4755 \)
```

i.e., separate the `\(` and `\)` from the adjacent arguments (with spaces).

Comment: The slash used in front of the octal permissions will cause a syntax error from `find`.

Comment: The slash used in front of permissions will likely be rejected by any [strictly POSIX-compliant version of `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47), as pointed out in [user3188445's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223361/23408), posted three weeks ago.  My answer works in the widely-available GNU version of `find`.

Comment: Do you like to use a find implementation that needs the option `-noleaf` in order to work correctly? Do you know that this is required to make gfind to work correctly?